# What's with i7 7700 throttling?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, cpu, throttling, stress-test

Hardware:

- Motherboard: Asus H170-Pro
- CPU: i7 7700 (Stock cooler)
- GPU: ZT-P10810F-10P (ZOTAC 1080 Ti AMP Extreme Core Edition)
- RAM: 16GB

Software:

- Windows 7 x64
- AIDA64 Extreme
- Games

Issues:

1. Why could games like "Homefront: The Revolution", "Conan Exiles" etc. give **~27 FPS** at **1920x1080** (Ultra Graphics)? (also, sometimes gives ~30 FPS at GTA V, Fallout 4 using **3840x2160** (Ultra Graphics) and any game at 4K gives **~20-30 FPS**)
2. Why a CPU's throttling doesn't go above 0% and doesn't turn off? (by the way, at the start a CPU's Throttling doesn't seem to be enabled, but after some time while having a stress test it turned on, is it?) *(please, take a look at picture below)*

[image: cpu_1]

Does that mean that Throttling didn't turn off? (this's about ~5 minutes on second picture's graph below) Should it turn off by itself?

[image: cpu_2]

---

Also, that how **Intel Extreme Tuning Utility** and **AIDA64 Extreme** while both running stress test look like:

AIDA64 Extreme:
[image: cpu_3]

Intel Extreme Tuning Utility:
[image: cpu_4]

Thank you very much,

Best regards

Comment: If your CPU is throttling it’s overheating. If it’s overheating there is something wrong with your cooling system. That is what you should be worried about. Once that is fixed, then you won’t need to worry about if it’s throttling or not.

Comment: Thank you @Appleoddity. We're working on that. There's also interesting if it's could be a reason that big amount of games may give low fps even at 1920x1080 and also crash at random time?